# Как удалить много записей из базы данных

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure

Простое удаление работает очень долго (около 40 секунд из одной таблицы, в которой примерно 1,5 миллиона записей), нужно сделать быстрее (нужно удалить все данные пользователя).
База MSSQL.

Comment: А удаляемых записей сколько. Имеются ли внешние ключи, ссылающиеся на таблицу с удаляемыми записями. Сколько индексов создано на этой таблице.

Comment: Да, поподробнее бы: из таблицы удаляются _вообще все_ данные, или часть данных удаляется, а часть остаётся? Как выбираются строки для удаления (по ключу или по другим полям), есть ли индексы?

Comment: Задан один индекс, по двух полях.

Comment: Из таблицы удаляются все данные, которые связаны с пользователем (поиск по id пользователя)

Comment: судя по времени, за раз удаляется несколько тысяч строк, это так?

Comment: Так сколько же все таки удаляемых записей. 1, 100, 10k, 100k ? id пользователя стоит первым полем в том индексе, который создан "по двух полях" ? внешние ключи на таблицу отсутствуют ?

Comment: Да, так, пытался удалять по несколько штук, особо скорости не прибавилось...(

Comment: Примерное количество удаляемых записей 5000. Индекс по других полях, по id нет индекса, если добавить индекс по id, то будет быстрее?
Внешних ключей нет.

Comment: @AndrijM А сколько времени работает select count(1) from table where user_id=XX ? Индекс конечно замедлит саму операцию удаления, и вставки в таблицу заодно, но зато он позволит найти те записи, которые надо удалять гораздо быстрее. Если select count() то же сильно тормозит, попробуйте создать индекс и посмотреть что получится

Comment: _"если добавить индекс по id, то будет быстрее?"_ при таких вводных (5к записей из 1,5м) думаю, что - да, без индекса вероятнее всего идёт сканирование _всей_ таблицы (или кластерного индекса), чтобы найти нужные записи.

Comment: а если коли чество больше чем 5к? Если 20к? Стоит добавлять индекс?

Comment: @AndrijM А вы эти записи по user_id ищете только при удалении, в системе больше нигде поиск по id пользователя в этой таблице не происходит ?

Comment: Больше нигде поиск не происходит, только при удалении.

Comment: Без знания структуры данных и индексов, а также количества строк и частоты их обновления в фоне все ответы будут "пальцем в небо".

Comment: На мой взгляд - если удаление частая операция, либо относительно нечастая, но всё же критичная по времени, то индекс стоит добавить. _"Если 20к?"_ я бы добавил. Только не спрашивайте "а если 100к?". :) Да возможно будет некий порог, после которого query processor может решить, что быстрее будет пойти table scan-ом, чем index seek. Порог этот будет зависеть от данных и достоверности статистик.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если нужно удалить ВСЕ записи из некоторой таблицы, используйте TRUNCATE, предварительно удалив внешние ключи, которые ссылаются на таблицу.
Это самый быстрый способ. Он, в частности, игнорирует триггеры.

Если просто большое количество, то нужно удалять пачками.
Оптимизировал я job, который удалял устаревшие данные, порядка ~100млн. строк в неделю. запускался на выходных. Опытным путём пришёл к выводу, что быстрее всего строки удаляется пачками по 100-500 штук.

Создаём временную табличку с ID'ами записей которые будем удалять.
Пишем туда 100-500 ID'ов. и вызываем:

```
DELETE T2
FROM #Table T1
  INNER LOOP JOIN Table T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Здесь нужен именно LOOP. Хотя сервер скорее всего и без хинтов догадается.
Вместо ID таблицы Table, может быть любой уникальный ключ. 
В случае, если ключ кластерный, то в таблицу #Table желательно вставлять ID'ы пачек строк, которые записаны в Table "рядом".

Если целиком пачку удалить не удалось, вызываем удаление по одной записи и логируем результаты.(ну я так делал:)) потом утром анализируем.

**UPD**: по поводу быстрого поиска удаляемых записей. **Стоит** создать индекс по UserId и посмотреть станет лучше или нет.

**UPD**: чуть-чуть про то, почему именно пачками.

Удаление по одной записи - это N транзакций. Выполняется довольно медленно... Таким был job до того, как я начал его оптимизировать.
Пытаться удалить одним DML оператором ~1млн строк тоже плохо. Т.к. сама транзакция становится очень большой и рискуем получить нехватку памяти.
Да и выполняется это долго.

В итоге задавая размер пачки, я к каждой таблице подобрал оптимальное число одновременно удаляемых записей. Начальник был доволен(с) :)

Comment: согласен. спасибо, себе тоже возьму на вооружение! Ранее пользовался дропов всей таблицы и создание новой. :)

Comment: @VladimirCh, это про TRUNCATE? Не за что:)

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Там только нюанс есть такой, что `truncate` не сработает, если есть внешние ключи, ссылающиеся на таблицу.

Comment: @i-one, так оно и логично. Дропнуть и пересоздать таблицу внешний ключ так же помешает. В ответ добавил, спасибо. пс: а как вы делаете моноширный шрифт в комментариях?

Comment: @i-one, спасибо!